# Is there Domain invariance for manifolds with boundary in some sense?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

It is well known that for manifolds without boundary, there exist a domain invariance theorem in the following form.

**Theorem.**
A subspace in an $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary is open if and only if 
it is an $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary.

I am curious on the case of manifolds with boundary. That is

Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary, then whether $A\subset M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary if and only if it is an open subspace contained in the interior of $M$?

Comment: You have to add the requirement that $(A,\partial A)\subset (M, \partial M)$ (in the case when $A$ is a manifold with the boundary $\partial A$): Then the invariance of domain holds.

Comment: @studiosus You answered my question in the title. I understand your point. You are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only need to proof that if $A$ is an $n$-manifold without boundary, then it is open in the $M$.

In fact, the answer of this question is very simple. The idea comes from 
Anton Petrunin, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191422.

Let's construct a new manifold without boundary by doubling $M$, denoted by $\widetilde M$.
By the domain invariance for manifolds, $A$ is an open subspace in $\widetilde M$.
Hence it is open in $M$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. For a 1-dimensional counterexample, take $M=[0,1]$ and $A=[1/4,3/4]$.

Comment: In your example, $A$ is a manifold with boundary and is contained in the interior of $M$, However, it is not an open subspace.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer. I thought you answered my question in the body. I have corrected the title a little.